# Convert dict to list of dict for each combinations

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dict looks like this :

```
my_dict = {
    "a":[1, 2, 3],
    "b":[10],
    "c":[4, 5],
    "d":[11]
}
```

And I would like to obtain a list containig all combinations keeping keys and value like this:

```
result = [
    {"a":1, "b":10, "c":4, "d":11},
    {"a":1, "b":10, "c":5, "d":11},
    {"a":2, "b":10, "c":4, "d":11},
    {"a":2, "b":10, "c":5, "d":11},
    {"a":3, "b":10, "c":4, "d":11},
    {"a":3, "b":10, "c":5, "d":11}
]
```

Do someone have a solution for this ?
Is there any existing solution to do this, or how should I proceed to do it myself ?

Thank you.

Comment: I hope using itertools.combinations you can generate various combinations of a list but not sure on generating for a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
def permute(d):
    k = d.keys()
    perms = itertools.product(*d.values())
    return [dict(zip(k, v)) for v in perms]
```

Example usage:

```
>>> d = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [10], 'c': [4, 5], 'd': [11]}

>>> pprint(permute(d))
[{'a': 1, 'b': 10, 'c': 4, 'd': 11},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 10, 'c': 5, 'd': 11},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 10, 'c': 4, 'd': 11},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 10, 'c': 5, 'd': 11},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 10, 'c': 4, 'd': 11},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 10, 'c': 5, 'd': 11}]
```

Answer (score 2):

A task for [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for dict_items in product(*[product([k],v) for k, v in my_dict.items()]):
...    print(dict(dict_items))

{'a': 1, 'b': 10, 'c': 4, 'd': 11}
{'a': 1, 'b': 10, 'c': 5, 'd': 11}
{'a': 2, 'b': 10, 'c': 4, 'd': 11}
{'a': 2, 'b': 10, 'c': 5, 'd': 11}
{'a': 3, 'b': 10, 'c': 4, 'd': 11}
{'a': 3, 'b': 10, 'c': 5, 'd': 11}
```

Small explanation:

The inner `product(...)` will expand the dict to a list such as `[[(k1, v11), (k1, v12), ...], [(k2, v21), (k2, v22), ...], ...]`.

The outer `product(...)` will reassemble the items lists by choosing one tuple from each list.

`dict(...)` will create a dictionary from a sequence of `(k1, v#), (k2, v#), ...` tuples.

Comment: Thanks for explanations ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are only interested in my_dict having 4 keys, it is simple enough to use nested for loops:

```
my_dict = {
    "a": [1, 2, 3],
    "b": [10],
    "c": [4, 5],
    "d": [11]
}

result = []
for a_val in my_dict['a']:
    for b_val in my_dict['b']:
        for c_val in my_dict['c']:
            for d_val in my_dict['d']:
                result.append({'a': a_val, 'b': b_val, 'c': c_val, 'd': d_val})

print(result)
```

This gives the expected result.

Comment: Thank you for answer but I can't use it because "my_dict" can contain different number of key with different name.

Comment: No problem.  Then the `itertools` approach is definitely the right one!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
from itertools import product
allNames = sorted(my_dict)
values= list(product(*(my_dict[Name] for Name in allNames)))
d = list(dict(zip(['a','b','c','d'],i)) for i in values)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 1, 'c': 4, 'b': 10, 'd': 11}, 
{'a': 1, 'c': 5, 'b': 10, 'd': 11}, 
{'a': 2, 'c': 4, 'b': 10, 'd': 11}, 
{'a': 2, 'c': 5, 'b': 10, 'd': 11}, 
{'a': 3, 'c': 4, 'b': 10, 'd': 11}, 
{'a': 3, 'c': 5, 'b': 10, 'd': 11}]
```

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.product` produces the combinations of a list of iterators.

`dict.values()` gets the list needed.

For each combination, `zip` up the `dict.keys()` with the combination.

Use a `list comprehension` to collect them up:

```
from itertools import product
from pprint import pprint

my_dict = {
    "a":[1, 2, 3],
    "b":[10],
    "c":[4, 5],
    "d":[11]
}

result = [dict(zip(my_dict,i)) for i in product(*my_dict.values())]
pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 10, 'c': 4, 'd': 11},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 10, 'c': 5, 'd': 11},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 10, 'c': 4, 'd': 11},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 10, 'c': 5, 'd': 11},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 10, 'c': 4, 'd': 11},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 10, 'c': 5, 'd': 11}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation ! It's more clear now ;)